# Spring framework web tutorial 404

Tags: spring, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I've just started learning the spring framework and honestly I can't even complete a tutorial made on this site :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm
nor this one:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

After doing both of these tutorial I got the same error:

> *HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.*

I even tried it without doing this step: "save your HelloWeb.war file in Tomcat's webapps folder." and instead I just ran it in eclipse.
It didn't work.

I've allready tryed numerous fixes over the last too days mostly posted here on stackoverflow, but non of them worked.

I'm using latest spring libs ,tomcat 7.0 and latest eclipse release.

Answer (score 0):

what i've noticed so far...

1st - HelloWeb-servlet.xml : i've changed xsd from 3.0 to 3.2 (current version of framework installed on my machine is 3.2.2 , i don't know why 3.0 returns error from Eclipse IDE nor did I decide to investigate further at this moment

2nd - the tutorial suggests you create Web.xml but instead you should create web.xml, i've noticed this while exploring the IDE and tried to see what servlets are installed and Eclipse told me that there are no servlets installed, no 'web.xml' found !

the app runs fine if you export WAR to Tomcat and access this link

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello
```